# Opening an app with the URL loaded in redirect-url from a server

Tags: android, url, redirect, android-intent

The set up:
A simple web server with one end point - /gotoapp - when it is called, it will redirect to an URL - myapp://callback/

An mobile App - with the following intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data
      android:host="callback"
      android:pathPrefix="/"
      android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Another mobile app with a button. On click of the button will load the URL: localhost:8080/gotoapp endpoint in a webview. In the response, the server will redirect to myapp://callback/.

I expect this redirection should open the Android app. But it throws Web page not available error in the webview.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the redirect URL is correct?

Comment: Yes @DavidWasser, I am sure on the redirect URL - myapp://callback/